# Is it valid to use "restrict" when there is the potential for reallocating memory (changing the pointer)?

Tags: c, restrict-qualifier

I am attempting some optimization of code, but it is hard to wrap my head around whether "restrict" is useful in this situation or if it will cause problems.

I have a function that is passed two strings (char*) as well as an int (int*).

The second string is copied into memory following the first string, at the position indicated by the int. If this would overrun the allocation of memory for the first string, it must reallocate memory for the first string before doing so. A new pointer is created with the new allocation, and then the original first string pointer is set equal to it.

```
char* concatFunc (char* restrict first_string, char* const restrict second_string, int* const restrict offset) {
size_t block = 200000;
size_t len   = strlen(second_string);
char* result = first_string;

if(*offset+len+1>block){
  result = realloc(result,2*block);
}
memcpy(result+*offset,second_string,len+1);
*offset+=len;
return result;
}
```

The above function is repeatedly called by other functions that are also using the restrict keyword.

```
char* addStatement(char* restrict string_being_built, ..., int* const restrict offset){
  char new_statement[30] = "example additional text";

  string_being_built = concatFunc(string_being_built,&new_statement,offset);
}
```

So in the concatFunc the first_string is restricted (meaning memory pointed to will not be changed from anywhere else). But then if I am reallocating a pointer that is a copy of that, is that going to cause undefined behavior or is the compiler smart enough to accommodate that?

Basically: What happens when you restrict a pointer parameter, but then change the pointer.

Comment: OT:  If you target string ever reaches `2 * block` in length, you're going to overflow the `result` buffer because you never grow it past `2 * block` bytes.

Comment: @AndrewHenle yes the actual logic is different I was just keeping it simple here

Comment: Doesn't `char* result = first_string;` break the restrict rule to begin with? Also note how `memcpy` requires that the memory location do not overlap (otherwise it's undefined behavior).
Other than that, I don't think the restrict keyword adds anything here. It may not be wrong (if `result` wasn't used as an alias), but I don't see any potential optimizations resulting from restricted pointers either.

Comment: @Yun " I don't see any potential optimizations resulting from restricted pointers either. " --> `*offset+=len;` is like `*offset=*offset + len;` and can take advantage that the prior `memcpy()` did not change the result of the earlier `*offset` calls.  Without `restrict` in `int* const restrict offset`, `*offset=*offset + len;` would have to reference `offset` to read `*offset`.

Comment: @DoritoJohnson Aside: The 2 `const` in `char* concatFunc (char* restrict first_string, char* const restrict second_string, int* const restrict offset) {` serve no purpose here to demonstrate the issue.  Clearer to demo this issue without them.  Dropping them does not change the function signature of `concatFunc()`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I see, thank you! Also, it turns out that aliasing a restricted pointer is actually fine ([ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What happens when you restrict a pointer parameter, but then change the pointer.

It depends on how the pointer was changed - and in this case, `memcpy()` risks UB.

With `char* result = first_string;`, inherits the `restrict` of `char* restrict first_string`.

After `result = realloc(result,2*block);`, `result` is as before and accessing via `result` does not collide with accessing through `second_string` or `offset` **or** `result` is new memory and accessing via `result` does not collide with accessing through `second_string` or `offset`.

Yet can the compiler *know*  the newly assigned `result` has those one of two above properties of `realloc()`?  After all, `realloc()` might be a *user* defined function and compiler should not assume `result` now has the `restrict` property anymore.

Thus `memcpy()` is in peril.

---

> is the compiler smart enough to accommodate that?

I do not see it can, other than warn about `memcpy()` usage.

Of course OP can use `memmove()` instead of `memcpy()` to avoid the concern.

---

As I see it, a simplified example would be:

```
char* concatFunc (char* restrict first_string, char* restrict second_string) {
  int block = rand();

  first_string = foo(first_string, block);

  // first_string at this point may equal second_string,
  // breaking the memcpy() contract

  memcpy(first_string, second_string, block);
  return first_string;
}
```

Or even simpler

```
char* concatFunc (char* /* no restrict */ first_string, char* restrict second_string) {
  return memcpy(first_string, second_string, 2);
}
```

Comment: "Yet can the compiler know the newly assigned result has those one of two above properties of realloc()? After all, realloc() might be a user defined function and compiler should not assume result now has the restrict property anymore." -->
Isn't qualifying a pointer with restrict a guarantee from the programmer to the compiler that this property holds? In other words, the compiler may assume `restrict` was used correctly and doesn't need to verify or infer anything.

Comment: @Yun Yes and no.  With an unaltered `first_string`, yes, I agree with you.  With a changed `first_string` (via `result = first_string; ... result = realloc(result, 2*block);`) one, I believe the compiler can and does assume `restrict` still applies.  But a problem here is that code relies on `realloc()` acting as we "know", when defensive coding would not assume that.

Comment: @Yun End thought: function parameters should use `restrict` when it is _clear_ no overlap is required **and** maintained throughout code. IMO, using the result of a non-`static` function does not maintain that guarantee.